# unresolved reference: GlobalScope.launch in vs code

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, kotlin-coroutines

I am getting unresolved references working with coroutines in Kotlin. I don't know how to update build.gradle file on vs code. Do I have to import some extensions or paths? Here's the code below

```
import kotlin.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    val states = arrayOf("Starting", "Doing Task 1", "Doing Task 2", "Ending")
    repeat(3) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            println("${Thread.currentThread()} has started")
            for(i in states) {
                println("${Thread.currentThread()} - $i")
                delay(5000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Output gives unresolved reference regarding GlobalScope.launch() and delay()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GlobalScope`, `launch` and `delay` are not part of the Kotlin standard library, they are part of the [Kotlinx coroutines library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines).

To use them, you need to add the coroutines library to your build.gradle(.kts):

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0")
}
```

And then import these declarations:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
```

As a side note, you shouldn't use `GlobalScope` unless you know what you're doing, and I guess you're just learning coroutines right now so you may want to avoid using this. In general, you should use a coroutine scope that is tied to some component with a lifecycle instead.

In this case, you probably want to use `runBlocking { ... }`  around the body of your main method, which will block the main thread while you're waiting for your coroutines.

Comment: You guessed it right, I was trying to get concepts of coroutines- why it is useful and why it's not. My VS code editor is just a text editor setup(one kt file and one jar file). I don't know where to find or how to create build.gradle file unless I am working on apps on android studio (build.gradle exists by default). Can you assist me with that? Appreciate your time

Comment: If you want to work with dependencies, it's usually easier with a build tool rather than manually compiling this with downloaded jars and a classpath crafted by hand. I'm not familiar with VS Code, but sometimes IDEs provide a built-in build system. If you're ok with using Gradle, you should be able to setup your project just like with Android Studio independently of the IDE you use (which is why I prefer this option). For instance, place your kotlin files under `src/main/kotlin` and create a new `build.gradle` file at the root of your project.